# libxml++ C++ find node by name

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I am parsing xml files from wikimedia using libxml++. I have been able to use the textparser to push the text from all nodes onto a stack, but I want to specifically grab text between the page and /page as well as getting the text, author name, and title. I am at a loss for how to do this with libxml++. Here is a sample of a page from wikimedia

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.7/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.7/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.7.xsd" version="0.7" xml:lang="en">
  <page>
    <title>Human Anatomy/Osteology/Axialskeleton</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>181313</id>
    <revision>
      <id>1481605</id>
  <parentid>1379871</parentid>
  <timestamp>2009-04-26T02:03:12Z</timestamp>
  <contributor>
    <username>Adrignola</username>
    <id>169232</id>
  </contributor>
  <minor/>
  <comment>+Category</comment>
  <sha1>hvxozde19haz4yhwj73ez82tf2bocbz</sha1>
  <text xml:space="preserve">[[Image:Axial_skeleton_diagram.svg|thumb|240px|right|Diagram of the axial skeleton]]

The Axial Skeleton is a division of the human skeleton and is named because it makes up the longitudinal ''axis'' of the body. It consists of the skull, hyoid bone, vertebral column, sternum and ribs. It is widely accepted to be made up of 80 bones, although this number varies from individual to individual.

[[Category:{{FULLBOOKNAME}}|{{FULLCHAPTERNAME}}]]</text>
</revision>
```

How do I save text, author, date etc. nodes as strings or Glib::ustrings? I tried using xpath to avail.
thank you for any help, and this is not homework.

-gtk